# I want to replace a special character with a space

Tags: python

Here is the code i have until now :

```
dex = tree.xpath('//div[@class="cd-timeline-topic"]/text()')
names = filter(lambda n: n.strip(), dex)
table = str.maketrans(dict.fromkeys('?:,'))
for index, name in enumerate(dex, start = 0):

print('{}.{}'.format(index, name.strip().translate(table)))
```

The problem is that the output will print also strings with one special character  "My name is/Richard". So what i need it's to replace that special character with a space and in the end the printing output will be "My name is Richard". Can anyone help me ?

Thanks!

Comment: Would you include a [MCVE]? Have you tried simply the `string.replace` method to remove the "special character"? Is the "special character" just a forward slash? It's not really clear what you're asking at this point.

Comment: You don't have a slash in your translation table...

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `dict.fromkeys()` does not include the character `/` in its argument.

If you want to map all the special characters to `None`, just passing your list of special chars to `dict.fromkeys()` should be enough. If you want to replace them with a space, you could then iterate over the dict and set the value to  for each key.

For example:

```
special_chars = "?:/"
special_char_dict = dict.fromkeys(special_chars)
for k in special_char_dict:
    special_char_dict[k] = " "
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by extending your translation table:

```
dex = ["My Name is/Richard????::,"]
table = str.maketrans({'?':None,':':None,',':None,'/':' '})
for index, name in enumerate(dex, start = 0):

    print('{}.{}'.format(index, name.strip().translate(table)))
```

OUTPUT

```
0.My Name is Richard
```

You want to replace most special characters with `None` BUT forward slash with a space.  You could use a different method to replace forward slashes as the other answers here do, or you could extend your translation table as above, mapping all the other special characters to `None` and forward slash to space.  With this you could have a whole bunch of different replacements happen for different characters.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working like i  want. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use `re.sub` function following way:

```
import re
s = 'Te/st st?ri:ng,'
out = re.sub(r'\?|:|,|/',lambda x:' ' if x.group(0)=='/' else '',s)
print(out) #Te st string
```

Arguments meaning of `re.sub` is as follows: first one is pattern - it informs `re.sub` which substring to replace, `?` needs to be escaped as otherwise it has special meaning there, `|` means: or, so `re.sub` will look for `?` or `:` or `,` or `/`. Second argument is function which return character to be used in place of original substring: space for `/` and empty `str` for anything else. Third argument is string to be changed.

Comment: Thank you for your help and explanations :)

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> a = "My name is/Richard"
>>> a.replace('/', ' ')
'My name is Richard'
```

Answer (score -1):

To replace any character or sequence of characters from the string, you need to use `.replace()' method. So the solution to your answer is:

```
name.replace("/", " ")
```

[here you can find details](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm)